# How to access a data table column that has special characters or space?

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table:

```
              Date     Time User% Sys% Wait% Idle% Busy PhysicalCPUs 
1: 01-APR-2015 00:15:28   0.7  0.9   0.1  98.4   NA            64
2: 01-APR-2015 00:30:32   0.7  0.9   0.3  98.1   NA            64
3: 01-APR-2015 00:45:39   0.5  0.7   0.3  98.4   NA            64
4: 01-APR-2015 01:00:46   0.6  0.8   0.3  98.3   NA            64
5: 01-APR-2015 01:15:51   0.5  0.7   0.1  98.6   NA            64
```

And I'm trying to plot a graphic with the following code:

```
g1 <- ggplot(CPU_ALL, aes(x = interaction(CPU_AL$Date, CPU_ALL$Time)
        , y = CPU_ALL$User%)) +
        geom_line() + 
        geom_point() +
        expand_limits(y=0) +
        xlab('Date/Time') + ylab('CPU Utilization (%)') +
        ggtitle('CPU ALL')
```

Afer run I get the following message:

```
anobre@segall:nmon$ CPU_ALL.R CPU_ALL_nmon.csv  
Error: unexpected input in: "g1 <- ggplot(CPU_ALL, aes(x = interaction(Date, Time)
        , y = User%)) +" Execution halted
```

I think the problem is when I try to access the columns `User%`, `Sys%`, `Wait%`, and `Idle%`. When I do `CPU_ALL[,Date]` it works fine, but when I try `CPU_ALL[,User%]` I get the following error message:

```
anobre@segall:nmon$ CPU_ALL.R CPU_ALL_nmon.csv 
Error: unexpected input in "CPU_ALL[,User%]"
Execution halted
```

Does anyone know how to access column names with special characters or spaces inside a data.table?

Comment: i think the reason it introduced some non-printable characters I suppose.

Comment: hi Anderson Nobre, if you have tried my solution and it worked, its a good practice to accept the answer. It will help others who are facing this similar problem and will increase my reputation.

Comment: use backticks to escape any non-standard name in R

Comment: I would suggest something like `setnames(CPU_ALL, gsub("\\.+", "_", make.names(names(CPU_ALL))))` in order to fix your column names once and for all

Comment: @DavidArenburg that suggestion makes all sort of strange assumptions. I use weird column names all the time, and consider it a big plus of `data.table` that it's nonplussed by them.

Comment: Great tip guys!!! Thank you all very much!!! Now it's working!!! I used backtip (`) and now it's working fine!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use backtick `` ` ``
 sign.

```
library(data.table)
CPU_ALL=data.table(`User%`=1:2)
CPU_ALL$`User%`
# [1] 1 2
CPU_ALL[,`User%`]
# [1] 1 2
CPU_ALL[,.(`User%`)]
#    User%
# 1:     1
# 2:     2
CPU_ALL[`User%` %in% 1:2]
#    User%
# 1:     1
# 2:     2
CPU_ALL[["User%"]]
# [1] 1 2
```

It will work for space also.

Answer (score 0):

if your column names have special characters wrap it in double quotes `""`

working script

```
g1 <- ggplot(CPU_ALL, aes(x = interaction(CPU_ALL$Date, CPU_ALL$Time)
                          , y = CPU_ALL$"User%")) +
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point() +
    expand_limits(y=0) +
    xlab('Date/Time') + ylab('CPU Utilization (%)') +
    ggtitle('CPU ALL')
```

If you would have read it from a file using `read.table` function and param `check.names=TRUE` which is btw default value of this param it would have automatically converted your data to

```
          Date     Time User. Sys. Wait. Idle. Busy PhysicalCPUs
1: 01-APR-2015 00:15:28   0.7  0.9   0.1  98.4   NA           64
2: 01-APR-2015 00:30:32   0.7  0.9   0.3  98.1   NA           64
3: 01-APR-2015 00:45:39   0.5  0.7   0.3  98.4   NA           64
4: 01-APR-2015 01:00:46   0.6  0.8   0.3  98.3   NA           64
5: 01-APR-2015 01:15:51   0.5  0.7   0.1  98.6   NA           64
```

see how `%` signs have been converted to `.` and then you could have directly accessed column without wrapping in double quotes.

```
g1 <- ggplot(CPU_ALL, aes(x = interaction(CPU_ALL$Date, CPU_ALL$Time)
                          , y = CPU_ALL$User.)) +
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point() +
    expand_limits(y=0) +
    xlab('Date/Time') + ylab('CPU Utilization (%)') +
    ggtitle('CPU ALL')
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use quotes: `CPU_ALL[,'User%']`

Comment: this will not work with data.table unless you use `with` argument.